# Is it possible to dynamically construct the SQL query where clause in ArcGIS layer based on the URL parameters?

Tags: sql, query

I have an ArcGIS layer published to my local server at:

```
https://baseURL/myMapServer/0
```

I want to dynamically construct the query where clause for this layer based on the URL. For example:

```
https://baseURL/myMapServer/0?category=cat1
```

would effectively translate into the following where clause:

```
category='cat1'
```

How can I accomplish this?

The arcgsis documentation touches on the topic:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/query-layers/update-parameter-values-in-a-query-layer.htm

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/sharing-collaboration/sharing-collaboration/using-url-parameters-in-web-apps/

https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/arcgisonline/query-a-feature-layer/

And I've tried:

https://baseURL/myMapServer/0/?query=category=cat1

and then,in definition query:
category=::category

But it doesn't work, ArcMap throws an SQL syntax error.

Update: this question is specifically on how defining ArcGIS layers. This is not a question on how to retrieve GET query parameters in PHP, JavaScript or any common programming langauge.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using javascript, you can create a query from your feature layer https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#createQuery

```
var layer = new FeatureLayer({
  url: "https://baseURL/myMapServer/0"
});

var queryParams = layer.createQuery();
queryParams.where = "category = 'cat1'";

layer.queryFeatures(queryParams).then(function(res){
  ...
});
```

or if you want to build the URL :
   https://baseURL/myMapServer/0/query?where=category%3D'cat1'

Answer (score -1):

What are you using on your local server?

What you have is a GET request. With PHP for example, you need to do something along the lines of:

```
$cat = $_GET['category'];
```

This will assign the value - in your example of `"cat1"` - to the variable `$cat`. You then proceed with building your SQL query and adding the `$cat` variable at the appropriate location.

Anyway, you need to look into how to grab the value of your GET request. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. This is about arcgis, not how to retrieve query parameters from a GET request.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very ambiguous request.
If I understand correctly you need to extract info from a call (GET request) to ArcGIS Server's REST endpoint, so you already have the complete URL (generated from some app perhaps). In this case:

```
//example URL: http://baseURL/arcgis/rest/services/myMapServer/0/query?where=NAME+like+%27%25test%25%27+AND+OBJECTID+%3C+1000&f=html
const mySearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
for (const [key, value] of mySearchParams) { do what you want with them ... }
```

If you want to you can only get the **where** param:

```
mySearchParams.get('where')
//"NAME like '%test%' AND OBJECTID < 1000"
```

Read here:

https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Otherwise take a look at the ArcGIS Server REST API, more specifically the Query operation on a Map/Feature Service/Layer:
https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-map-service-layer-.htm
You can play with the web UI, there is a **where** clause you can apply as well.
The bad part is all other params get included in the GET request with no values.
Another VERY BAD "feature" of ArcGIS Server is that to this day it still responds with HTTP 200 to failed requests ...

Comment: This to clarify, this question is specifically on how to define an arcgis layer ousing Arc Map in a way that would let me access the query parameters and use them in the underlying SQL query. This is not a question on how to access query parameters in a GET request.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand the question, I see you have updated it. :)
So it's about query layers in ArcMap.